# Before Update Trigger in Phpmyadmin how to get updated values

Tags: triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get a trigger in phpmyadmin which would create a audit with a certain column value (`reputation`) before and after the update of a specific table.

Something like:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%`
TRIGGER `monitor update reputation`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `game_resorts`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `audit` (`id`, `datetime`, `id_resort`, `reputation`)
VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, id_resort, reputation)
```

The main question is how can I retrieve the `id_resort` which will be updated; and then, the `reputation` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL, you would use the `NEW` keyword, so I assume it would be the same using phpmyadmin.

For example:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`%`
TRIGGER `monitor_update_reputation` //don't use spaces in a trigger name
BEFORE UPDATE ON `game_resorts`
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO `audit` (`datetime`, `id_resort`, `reputation`) 
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NEW.id_resort, NEW.reputation)
```

If you want to get the value of `id_resort` or `reputation` *before* the update, you can use the `OLD` keyword:

```
...
VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, OLD.id_resort, OLD.reputation)
```

Also, I don't think you can insert `NULL` into a primary key column.  If your `id` on the `audit` table is set to auto increment, you can simply omit the `id` column from the `INSERT` statement.